# How to read multiple files to save and count number of variables in each using a map_* function from purrr?

Tags: r, tidyr, purrr, readxl

I read multiple files using `map_dfr()` and nest the data using the following codes:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("readxl")

files <- c("file1.xlsx", "file2.xlsx", "file3.xlsx", "file4.xlsx")

df <- files %>% 
  set_names() %>% 
  map_dfr(read_excel, .id = "File") %>% 
  group_by(File) %>% 
  nest()
```

And the dataframe `df` looks like this:

[image]

How can I use `mutate()` to add one column to save variable names in each data and another column to count how many variables? I tried this but it is not working:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(var.list = names(data)) %>% 
  mutate(var.n = unique(var.list))
```

My intention is to have a list column `var.list` to save variables (column names) from each data set and a column `var.n` to count the number of variables. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `... %>% mutate(var.list = map_chr(data, names), var.n = map_int(var.list, ~ length(unique(.)))` or similar.

Comment: The `$data` column is a *list-column*, so you have to deal with it as a `list`. This means using `lapply` or `sapply` or the `purrr::` equivalents.

Comment: (Correction, change `map_chr` to `map`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fake setup:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

set.seed(42)
df <- tibble(file = sprintf("file%i.xlsx", 1:3)) %>%
  mutate(data = map(file, ~ mtcars[,sample(11,size=7)]))
df
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   file       data             
#   <chr>      <list>           
# 1 file1.xlsx <df[,7] [32 x 7]>
# 2 file2.xlsx <df[,7] [32 x 7]>
# 3 file3.xlsx <df[,7] [32 x 7]>
```

The work:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(
    var.list = map(data, colnames),
    var.n = map_int(var.list, ~ length(unique(.)))
  ) %>%
  # and just to show the differencs
  mutate(
    var.names = map_chr(var.list, toString)
  )
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#   file       data              var.list  var.n var.names                          
#   <chr>      <list>            <list>    <int> <chr>                              
# 1 file1.xlsx <df[,7] [32 x 7]> <chr [7]>     7 mpg, drat, carb, am, cyl, hp, qsec 
# 2 file2.xlsx <df[,7] [32 x 7]> <chr [7]>     7 gear, mpg, vs, qsec, hp, carb, drat
# 3 file3.xlsx <df[,7] [32 x 7]> <chr [7]>     7 hp, gear, cyl, qsec, disp, mpg, wt
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Could you explain why `mutate(var.list = colnames(data))` doesn't work?

Comment: For the same reason that `colnames(list(iris,iris))` won't work, because `$data` is a *list-column* (meaning it's a `list` of frames).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I also tried `mutate(var.list = colnames(data[[1]]))` and it doesn't work either. In this case, `data[[1]]` is a dataframe already. Why?

Comment: Because `n()` and `length(colnames(data[[1]]))` are unlikely to be the same. That is, you can't do `mtcars %>% mutate(abc = 1:7)` when there are 32 rows; the assignment length *must* be an even divisor of the number of rows, and in my opinion *should* be one of `1L` or `n()` (not just a divisor . .. R's recycling can be bad for data).